# Proof of Vedic or Indic origin of Vaishnavism (Monotheistic Supremacy of Vishnu)?

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, ramanujacharya, pancharatra, madhvacharya

**Edit: This question is not a duplicate as it is asking about the specific verses mentioned and not a generic question about Vedic Vasihnavism. Please know the difference.**

---

I was watching a Christian apologist [video](https://youtu.be/fbu7670xRcA) (also [related](https://youtu.be/cE7aVQn-jjM)) and they were saying that in Vedas, which are ancient, the religion was polytheistic and not monotheistic and Lord Vishnu was a minor god, not the supreme monotheistic God as modern Vaishnavites practice. Their claim is that Hindus took monotheistic doctrine from Jew and Old Testament around 400 to 500 BCE, and superimposed it with minor Vedic God Vishnu hence creating Vaishnavite systems like Pancharatra etc.

And in their support they cite Vedic verses where Vishnu is subservient to Indra and is seemingly a minor God.

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

Now my question is:

1. Is it true that Vishnu is a minor God in the Vedas, who later became a major God? If no how do you explain the verses mentioned above and how do you establish the supremacy of Vishnu in the Vedas?
2. Is it possible to show that, if not Vedic, the origin of Vaishnavism was Indic, that Vaishnavite texts, proclaiming supremacy of Vishnu existed in India long before the advent of Jews? Maybe by the dating of Pancaratra, Vishnu Purana or Mahabharata?

---

Note: This question is not opinion based as I'm asking verses and internal scriptural evidence of Vaishnavism and also this question is very important for Hindus.

---

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan need your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How has Lord Vishnu's understanding developed and what was his role initially?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6870/how-has-lord-vishnus-understanding-developed-and-what-was-his-role-initially)

Comment: @Rickross thank you for the link. But I wanted resolution for  the above mentioned verses and chronology of Vaishnavism which is not discussed in the other question.

Comment: Aitareya Brahmana 1.1.1 and Taittiriya Samhita 5.5.5.1 - Among all the gods Agni is the lowest and Vishnu is the highest.

Comment: Taittiriya Samhita 1.7.4 - yagno vai vishnuh, (yagna is indeed vishnu)Adi Shankara quotes this at a couple of places in his Gita bhashya and he equates Vishnu to Ishwara in this context. Adi Shankara also mentions in this context that Vishnu is the presiding deity of all yagnas. These samhitas and brahmanas are probably pre-jew?

Comment: @zero thank you, but if Vishnu is the highest then why does he serve and cook for Indra. Why is he called Upendra??

Comment: In the Rig Veda samhita, Vishnu is not the major god. However, it is debatable how much the Rig Veda samhita really represented the religion of the masses of that day. On a different note, Rig veda samhita is mostly concerned about karma and not brahman. If it were the latter, Adi Shankara would have commented on it.

Comment: @zero here's the problem, the entire argument of Vedantic group like Adi Shankaracharya relies on the infallibility of Vedas as they being Apourusheya or Unauthored. So every sentence in Vedas must be true and cannot be somebody's opinion lile Puranas. Therefore we need to explain the verses where Vishnu is supposedly serving Indra.

Comment: I thought your question was from a historical perspective. From a traditional perspective, at least in some traditions, most of RV is karma kanda. One explanation could be that Vishnu is helping Indra in his vamana avatara. As vamana, vishnu is upendra, the younger brother of Indra. I will not be surprised if this explanation is not convincing.

Comment: Every sentence in vedas need not be literally true. Purva mimamsa believes in apaurusheyatva but considers upanishads as arthavAda.

Comment: @zero yes exactly that's what I'm asking, what is the arthavada here?? Every sentence in Vedas is either literally true or metaphorically true. As this is not literal what is the metaphorical meaning?

Comment: @zero also I don't believe there is a traditional view and there is a historical view. The historical view is the traditional view and vice versa. If not then the tradition is lying.

Comment: @zero and the vamana theory is very good, but do Vedas directly refer to the Vamana avatar?? That means Vedas were composed after Vamana avatar, but Vedas are supposed to be eternal also were Vedas not present before Vamana avatar during Matsya and Varaha avatar??

Comment: I have actually attempted to explain it literally - that vishnu here is vamana avatara. Its not my intention to brush it aside as arthaAda. I talked of arthavAda in the context of vedas not being considered literally true by all astikas.

Comment: Sir, you are digressing to the topic of vedic eternality etc. Its not a topic that I want to get into. I only tried to address the point raised in this specific question.

Comment: @zero yes yes sorry for that, I got a little too curious, but this is what one has to deal when debating with people like I have linked in the question

Comment: @zero please consider writing an answer, your inputs are very valuable.

Comment: Thank you. I will write if I get the time.

Comment: Doesnt really matter because Vedic period considered all gods as one. This can be seen in Rig Veda's popular Ekam Sat Vipuda Vadanti and Yaska's Nirukta. For regards your questions, Every God is supreme as per Vedas. You have Sects of Vishnu Shiva Devi Ganesha and Smarta for this purpose. Yes indeed Vaishnavism existed long before Jews came to India and Jesus didnt even exist. You can read contradictions in Gospels and watch Richard Carrier or see "Jesus in Wonderland" in youtube

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru yes Jesus wasn't yet born but was Judaism already started?

Comment: @MrGreenGold :D Jews dont accept Jesus as a Messaih. Judaism and Christianity are much different. Judaism has nothing to do with Christ

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru no one's talking about Jesus. If you go to the link in the question, those people are accusing that Hindus took monotheism from Jews.

Comment: You asked <Jesus wasn't yet born but was Judaism already started>  @MrGreenGold

Comment: Please use chat-room for further discussion. Thanks

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru I mean Jews. Did Hindus take the concept of Monotheism from Jews.??

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru why are you bringing Jesus into this, please see the comments you have bought Jesus first. The question concerns only Jews and Hindus.

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru Jews had not come to come India, but Jews were already there and there was trade and migration going on.

Comment: They didn't. They didn't have to. Many sects like Vaishnavism and so on were existing much before they came. Even if I assume for worst case they did would that really matter ? Hinduism is knowing Atman, realising everything as Brahman and Ishwara or Bhagavan is worshipped and paid reverence in whatever form a devotee wants to. Which of these ideas are from Jews ? @MrGreenGold

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru some Christian apologists are arguing that Hindus took Monotheism and Supremacy of one God from Jews.

Comment: Let them : D First ask them to prove existence of their own holy Christ @MrGreenGold

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru but the claim is not related to Christ, its bw Jews and Hindus. Also Christ already proved by literary and archeological evidence. Almost everyone agrees Jesus was a real personility

Comment: Nobody agrees. Watch Vedios of Richard Carrier Bart Ehrman Christopher Hitchens and Earl Doughty.  Watch this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1U80HkLbTHI&t=12s

Yes I told you the claim is foolish. You need not hear to every such fool. Hindus simply didnt copy any monothiesm concept from Jews. @MrGreenGold

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru I'm sorry but that is some second rate conspiracy theory channel. All modern mainstream historians, both theists and atheists have accepted Jesus to be a real historical person.

Comment: While there is widespread scholarly agreement on the existence of Jesus,[f] and a basic consensus on the general outline of his life https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesus

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru please give sources which are authentic, not some radical conspiratorial proof. Majority of major historians agree Jesus was a real historical person.

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru one of the authors mentioned by you, Bart D Harman argues for the existence of Jesus. Look here Bart D. Ehrman, a scholar of the New Testament. In this book, written to counter the idea that there was never such a person as Jesus of Nazareth at all, Ehrman sets out to demonstrate the historical evidence for Jesus' existence, and he aims to state why all experts in the area agree that "whatever else you may think about Jesus, he certainly did exist."[1][2] https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Did_Jesus_Exist%3F_(Ehrman_book)

Comment: Did you even read completely what he says?. He is saying legendary stories were brought down on a guy who lived sometime ago. And he says all Gospels which are heart of Christianity are irrelevant and unreliable. Richard Carrier says that there were so many people like Jesus and stories attributed to them. Jesus may have lived but defently not as attributed in Gospels which are so mutually contradictory. My point is if they critisise you can also keep on critising something else in their religion which is much faulty than us. If not this you could choose so many.

Comment: You could read Kristamuta Chednam and so on. This is a joke if they say monotheism is borrowed from Judaism. Upanishads Mahabharata are much older than timeline when they came.  See this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Jews_in_India#Jewish_groups_in_India 
When Jews entered. Earliest date is during King Solomon i.e. 900 BC. How old is MB ?3000 BC. How old are Upanishads 5000 BC ++. Now how did Hindus copy monotheism from Jews ? @MrGreenGold

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru king Solomon was 900 BC, but Moses was there around 1200 BC. Also their claim is monotheism isn't present in Upanishads. That's what I'm asking in my new question monotheism in Upanishads where are the verses? Now  we don't know how old Mahabharata is?? How are we dating it?? Mahabharata is some where between 800 BC to 2400 BC approximately. But that's war date, when was it composed??

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/48776/22253

Comment: There are verses in Upanishads saying knowing this Purusha only one becomes immortal. And Brihadaranyaka summarises all Devatas as parts of your own Body. Are these proofs enough for you ? @MrGreenGold

Comment: Sayana himself didnt see Purusha Sukta as interpolation. I remember Ambedkar debunking Aryan Invasion of Muller by showing Sayana's Bhasya..

Comment: Yes Brihadaranyaka Upanishad is correct, that's why I've upvoted the answer given by PradipGangopadhyay.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have access to a Ramakrishna mission Bengali translation of Rig Veda Book 1. I have given my free translation of Rig Veda 1.22.16-21. These mantras treat Vishnu as Vaishnavas do. The idea that Vishnu is the preserver of the universe is there in the Rig Veda.

> Protect us Devas in this place where Vishnu has trodden in seven
> regions of the earth.

**Rig Veda 1.22.16**

> Vishnu has specially travelled the whole world. He had planted His
> foot three times. **The whole world is included in the dust of Vishnu’s
> footsteps.**

**Rig Veda 1.22.17**

> Vishnu had trodden the earth three steps [1], **He is the protector of
> all without being hurt by anyone and hence the protector of all
> dharmas.**

**Rig Veda 1.22.18**

[1] Vishnu as Vamana Avatara had taken three steps.

> Sayana’s interpretation: (O Ritviks!) Reflect on Vishu’s karma **which
> ensures success of austerities.** That same Vishnu is Indra’s friend.

> Jamieson and Griffith’s interpretation: Reflect on Vishnu’s karma from
> which Vishnu observes everything….That Vishnu is Indra’s friend.

**Rig Veda 1.22.19**

> The wise observe the holy place or footsteps of Vishnu the way an
> all-knowing eye observes from the earth.[2]

**Rig Veda 1.22.20**

[2] The above is a Vishnu mantra uttered at the start of a puja.

> The wise who are specially gifted with poetic power enkindle or
> lighten up the best footstep of Vishnu.

**Rig Veda 1.22.21**

I don't have the Bengalis translations of the other verses. So I will do my best.

The other 4 Rig Veda verses 2.22.1, 6.17.11, 8.15.8-9 and 8.66.10 are hymns to Indra. These are arthavad or eulogy and should not be taken literally. The hymns are meant to glorify Indra and show his greatness. As part of that the hymn says that Vishnu Himself is a dear friend of Indra and even cooks for him. This suggests that Vishnu is acknowledged to be great since otherwise the praise loses its meaning. Nobody would care if a loser is a friend of Indra.

The Aiteriya Brahmana verse 1.30 acknowledges that Vishnu is possessed of the greatest power and changes darkness to light. Then it says that Vishnu is the doorkeeper of the gods. Now we must remember that these gods are jivas who through extraordinary merits have becomes holders of high posts. So Vishnu of highest power cannot be subordinate to the gods. The only sane explanation is that the gods have to worship Vishnu in order to gain liberation. It is in that sense that Vishnu is the gatekeeper.

**Is Vaishnava monotheism copied from the Jewish Bible around 400-500 bce?**

The answer will depend on when the Jews became monotheistic and also if there was any connection between the Jews and the Hindus around 400-500 bce.

So let us first check when the Jews became monotheistic.

**When did Jews adopt the doctrine of monontheism?**

> At Kuntillet 'Arjud, a place in southern Israel, we find inscriptions
> dated to around the ninth to eighth centuries BCE. One of these
> inscriptions, which were published in the 1970s, speaks of the 'Yahweh
> of Samaria', the very type of designation Eichrodt tells us we would
> not find among Israelites. He claims that the designations of Yahweh
> as the God of Dan or Beersheba were denounced by Hebrew prophets
> (e.g., in Amos 8:14) precisely because they were Canaanite imports.
> But that alone tells us that such localized descriptions were found
> among Israelites. To say that this was an import even though almost
> every other major concept can be found among Israel's neighbors is the
> height of arbitrariness.
>
> The finds at Kuntillet'Arjud also effectively defeat another of
> Eichrodt's pronouncements: "Yahweh never had a consort; and thus any
> idea that he needed to be complemented - a fate which befell all the
> other major Semitic deities - was rejected. In fact, at
> Kuntillet'Arjud we find inscriptions that are plausibly translated as
> " To [Y]ahweh (of) Teiman, and to his Asherah." [1] Inscriptions dated
> to the eighth century BCE, and with similar references to Asherah as
> Yahweh's consort, were published earlier by William G. Dever at
> another site named Khirbet-el-Qom.[2]

[1] William G. Dever, Did God have a Wife? Archeology and Folk Religion in Ancient Israel (Grand Rapids, MI: Eerdmans, 2005), p 162 [2] Willaim G. Dever, Did God have a Wife? Archeology and Folk Religion in Ancient Israel, p 132

**The End of Biblical Studies, Biblical Theology: The Pathology of Bibliolatry, Hector Avalos, p 255.**

'**The Hebrew Goddess**' by Raphael Patai also discusses Jewish polytheism. There is evidence that Jews were polytheistic in the eighth century. However, by the time the c 600 ce text the Book of Exodus was written there is no doubt that Judaism was moving towards monotheism.

> **You shall have no other gods before me ... you shall not bow down to
> them or serve them;** for I the Lord your God am a jealous God, visiting
> the iniquity of the fathers upon the children to the third and the
> fourth generation of those who hate me.

**Exodus 20:1,5**

Of course the very fact that in the Book of Exodus Yahweh has to threaten his followers of dire consequence if they worship other god suggest that polytheism was considered a threat even in 600 BCE. **The exact date when Judaism became completely monotheistic is not known.**

**What do we know about the situation in India in the 600-300 BCE?**

There are 3 ancient sources which tell us about about India and Indians in this period.

The first one is 'The Histories' by Herodotus. He mentions about Indian mercenaries fighting for the Persians against the Greeks but does not say anything about their religion.

Alexander's invasion of India around 330 BCE resulted in some books describing India. They do not mention seeing any Jews in India.

The third one is by the Greek Ambassador of the court of Selucus, Megasthenes, in the Maurya court. He talks about a God named Heracles which some scholars think is Krishna. The fragments of his book that survive is silent on Jews in India.

From these three sources one can say with some reliability that Hindus had contact with Greeks and with Persians in the 600-400 BCE. Greeks were polytheists while Persians as Zoroastrians were monotheists. We simply do not find any recorded source that mentions any contact between Hindus and Jews in that period.

There seems to be greater possibility that Vaishnavism derived its monotheism from the Persians than from the Jews. In reality Vaishnava monotheism seems a product of India. This is clear from what Megasthenes wrote. Krishna (Heracles) was an important deity even around 300 bce. Mahabharata which is dated between 400 BCE to 400 CE clearly supports the idea that Krishna was an important deity even earlier. Mahabharata does not mention Jews anywhere in the text. Moreover Lord Krishna is mentioned in the Chandogya Upanishad.

> Ghora Angirasa expounded this well known doctrine to **Devaki's son
> Krishna** and said , 'Such a knower should at the time of death repeat
> this triad - "Thou art the imperishable, Thou art the unchangeable,
> Thou art the subtle essence of Prana." (on hearing the above) Krishna
> became thirstless. There are two Rk stanzas in regard to this.

**Chandogya Upanishad 3.17.6**

Chandogya Upanishad was composed around 900 BCE according to western scholars. The fact that such an old text mentions Sri Krishna suggests that Krishna was a very important deity even in 900 BCE when Judaism was most likely polytheist. So one could argue that early Vaishnavism predates monotheistic Judaism by a large margin.

The claim made by Christian apologists is an extraordinary one. As we have shown that when Judaism became monotheist is uncertain and that there is no evidence that there was any contact between Hindus and Jews in that time. In fact Hindus had much greater contact with Persians and Greeks. Thus the Christian apologists would need to give extraordinary proof of their extraordinary claim for anyone to believe them.

Comment: verses 2.22.1, 6.17.11, 8.15.8-9 and 8.66.10 are hymns to Indra, if these are arthavaad then  what is the metaphor. If Vishnu is great and is used for cooking and dancing for Indra, it only places Indra above Vishnu. There's also name Upendra. The problem is you can't say someone did it, because these are Vedas and Apaurusheya and no one did it. So I think there's some deeper esoteric meaning here. Also you have translation can you please give free translation of the above verses as well.

Comment: So when the mantras are on Indra they are arthavad but when they are on Vishnu they are literal?

Comment: @MrGreenGold,I don't have the Bengali translations of Books 2-10 of Rig Veda. I only have book 1 translations. This is the reason why I only wrote about Book 1 initially. You may well be right that there might be some deeper esoteric meaning. Unfortunately today no one knows about such a meaning.  I would wtite some more on it in my next comment.

Comment: @Rickross, We know in later times Indra's position is clearly below that of Vishnu. So if you want to be consistent with that then you have to make Indra's hymns arthavad and treat remarks on  Vishnu as literal. The problem, as mentioned in an introduction in the Ramakrishna Mission translation, is that today no one knows the esoteric meaning. The RKM editors found that most of the experts on Rig Veda are either dead or too old to be very useful. They said that nevertheless they will try their best. They seem to be using Sayanacharya and the latest western translation of Jamieson and Griffith.

Comment: No ancient commentary exists on Rig Veda. The oldest is only 600 years old and is interpreted from the Purva Mimamsa point of view. This absence of authoritative commentaries has given many western commentators a field day in interpreting the Rig Veda. This has also allowed Christian and Islamic people to mis-interpret the Rig Veda as they want. They will not find mis-interpreting the Upanishads or the Itihasas so easy.

Comment: Correction: The latest western translation is that of Jamieson and Brereton. I came across this youtube video that illustrates the various mis-interpretation of the Rig Veda. 
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KInMQrTl2NE

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay yes but there is Sayanacharya commentry on Rig Veda but no English translation is available. If available plz give link also please if you can answer the second part of the question.

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay can you please try to address the second question.

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay excellent 

Comment: @pradipgangopadhyay "Now we must remember that these gods are jivas who through extraordinary merits have becomes holders of high posts" -Godship was turned into a civil service only in the itihasapuranas.  Can't use that argument while discussing Rig Veda.

Answer (score 9):

**Summary** : The Vedas *DO NOT* declare Vishnu as a minor deity. He occupies very much the same lofty position as he always has. The verses are not accurately represented, but despite that is to be understood as reference to Lord Trivikrama, Indra’s younger brother, showing brotherly affection for him. There’s no labour involved.

---

**Detailed**
Obviously, just like [the Puranas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/43910/is-the-vedic-supreme-god-different-from-the-puranic-supreme-god/43915#43915), the Vedas too declare Brahman in a similar fashion, the very one for whom all scriptures are [supposed to be dedicated](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/48414/how-do-the-vedas-sing-at-the-beginning-middle-and-end-of-brahman). We shall restrict the discussion to only Shri Hari. As per the question there are some ‘apparently’ contradictory verses about him, which we shall sort below.

### The Supremacy of Shri Hari in the Rigveda

It is incorrect to say that Vedas do not proclaim Shri Hari as Brahman. One [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/48716/20129) already gives the Shadvaishnava verses which show Vishnu’s high position. In addition I’d like to state one more (taken from [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19872/do-any-vedic-verses-depict-lord-vishnu-to-be-supreme)):

> यः पू॒र्व्याय॑ वे॒धसे॒ नवी॑यसे सु॒मज्जा॑नये॒ विष्ण॑वे॒ ददा॑शति । यो जा॒तम॑स्य मह॒तो महि॒ ब्रव॒त्सेदु॒ श्रवो॑भि॒र्युज्यं॑ चिद॒भ्य॑सत् ॥
>
> Vishnu is the most ancient of all, yet also the most recent. Nothing and no one creates Vishnu, yet Vishnu creates everyone and everything.
> -*Rigveda 1.156.2*

Against the above translation, [Sayanacharya’s explanation](https://archive.org/details/RgVedaWithSayanasCommentaryPart1/page/n963/mode/2up) presents a slightly different and more convincing view. Some words are explained by him:

> 1. ‘पूर्व्याय’ पूर्वकालीनाय नित्यायेत्यर्थः - pūrvāya means ancient and must be understood as **nitya (eternal)**. 
>     2. ‘वेधसे’ विविधजगत्कर्त्रे - Vedhas means the **creator of  many jagats (worlds)**. 
>     3. ‘नवीयसे’ नित्यनूतनाय अत्यन्तरमणीयायेत्यर्थः - navīyas means one forever knew, to be understood as extremely pleasing to look at. 
>     4.‘जातं’ जन्म उत्पत्तिं हिरण्यगर्भादिरूपं जन्म - jata means birth in the from of Hiranyagarbha.

In fact, for the very next verse (1.156.3) Sayanacharya explains :

> विष्णोरेव स्वर्गापवर्गसाधनाय इष्ट्याद्यात्मना द्रव्यदेवतात्मना वा परिणामम् - Only **Vishnu is the facilitator of svarga and moksha**, he is the atman of the Yajna and the devata of the Dakshina or (and) the result as well.

Thus we can see that the supremacy of Narayana is upheld by the Rigveda samhita.

---

### Solving the ‘Apparent’ Contradiction

This will be done in two parts. First present a more accurate explanation for the verses quoted in the question, as per Sayanacharya. Second the reason for contradiction.

#### A. Sayanacharya’s explanation for the verses

From the below it will be seen that while giving a fairly accurate translation, how the verses in the question have been misrepresented in their titular summary.

1. Rigveda 2.22.1:
   The translation in the verse quoted says Indra drank (the poured out) Soma with Vishnu, yet the title *wrongly* says he pressed Soma for Indra. **As per Sayana too there’s no pressing (labour) by Vishnu**. He [simply says](https://archive.org/details/RgVedaWithSayanasCommentaryPart2/page/n141/mode/2up):

> तं सोमं विष्णुना सह अपिबत् - he drank that Soma with Vishnu.

2. Rigveda 6.17.11:
   In the very same translation quoted, the verse talks about a certain ‘he’ who has cooked buffaloes. That same ‘he’ together with Pushan and Vishnu poured 3 vessels of Soma for Indra. Thus this ‘he’ cannot be Vishnu who cooks. If one sees the [previous verses](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv06017.htm), it’s amply clear that this ‘he’ is Tvashta (explained by Sayanacharya as devatas architect). Although little confusing, Sayana too [says](https://archive.org/details/RgVedaWithSayanasCommentaryPart3/page/n159/mode/2up), ‘may he cook’ in singular form (पचेत्) and hence can’t refer to all 3 but only Tvashta. **There’s no cooking of beef by Vishnu.** Vishnu pusha Tvashta only pour the soma. Though little out of order, he says these 3 fill 3 vessels of Soma:

> सोमैः पात्राणि पूरयन्त इत्यर्थः - they fill the 3 vessels with Soma.

3. Rigveda 8.15.9 of the devatas praising Indra is correct, even as per [Sayana Bhashya](https://archive.org/details/RgVedaWithSayanasCommentaryPart3/page/n711/mode/2up)
4. Rigveda 8.66.10 quoted above doesn’t match with [Sayana’s 8.66.10](https://archive.org/details/RgVedaWithSayanasCommentaryPart3/page/n919/mode/2up) of the Rigveda. Hence not commenting. But let’s assume it’s true (it’ll be sorted below).

Thus we can see some claims made are not accurate, not even matching with the same translation given against it.

#### B. Explaining the ‘apparent’ contradiction

Though the claims have been proven inaccurate, the question still remains, why is Vishnu (declared supreme in the Rigveda) drinking Soma alongside Indra and why is he pouring him? Does the same person, whom the same Rigveda declares as eternal, do this?

**The answer is, ‘Vishnu’ has a dual meaning - Narayana as well as Trivikrama.** The person who’s pouring the soma is **to be understood as Vishnu in the form of Trivikrama, the son of Aditi and Kashyapa and Indra’s younger brother**, and not in the form of the eternal God. Proof of this is from the Rigveda itself. Please see the Shadvaishnava verse 1.22.17 and [Sayana’s explanation](https://archive.org/details/RgVedaWithSayanasCommentaryPart1/page/n195/mode/2up):

> इ॒दं **विष्णु॒र्वि च॑क्रमे त्रे॒धा नि द॑धे प॒दम्** । समू॑ळ्हमस्य पांसु॒रे॥
>
> Sayana says- विष्णुः त्रिविक्रमावतारधारी ... जगद् ... विशेषेण क्रमणं कृतवान्।  तदा त्रिभिः प्रकारैः स्वकीयं पादं प्रक्षिप्तवान्। सेयमृक् यास्केनैवं व्याख्याता - विष्णुर्विशतेर्वा ... यदिदं किंच विक्रमते विष्णुस्त्रिधा निधत्ते पदं...।
>
> **Vishnu in the form of Trivikrama transgressed the world. Then he cast his legs in *three* different ways**. This Rik has been explained by Yaska - Vishnu the one who pervades or the one who transgresses (pervades) the world, while placing his feet in 3 ways.

We can see that Vamana **is also called Vishnu not merely because of being Narayana, but because he became so huge that he pervaded bhu bhuvah svah.** In this case, it doesn’t mean Narayana who pervades all creation and hence called Vishnu. The word ‘Vishnu’ carries a dual meaning.

These words of the Veda and the relation between Indra and Vamana can be further  explained from the Harivamsa. In the [Govardhana episode](http://mahabharata-resources.org/harivamsa/vishnuparva/hv_2_019.html) similar to the ‘apparently’ confusing Vedic verses, **Indra too first acknowledges Narayana as of higher position than him, but is quick to go back to Upendra**. For example:

> [praising as higher] **Krishna, all the creations of this world are in your body.** This is as per the direction of brahma. You are among the gods , like gold in minerals. Even the self manifested brahma, with his knowledge and position, is unable to understand you, like a lame man who is unable to catch up with a fast runner. 
>  *Vishnu Parva verses 19.23-24*
>
> [Back to Upendra] People on the earth will **worship mahendra (me) and upendra (you)** with flags and sacrifices. 
> -*Vishnu Parva verse 19.58*

The above (first declare as supreme then younger brother) is because, though Indra knows who Vishnu is, yet he considers him as a younger brother (Harivamsa 2.19.37) and expects the same the same respect a younger sibling will give the older. This can be seen from Indra’s words when Krishna wants to take the Parijata from him, an event subsequent to Govardhana (where Indra himself acknowledges Narayana as higher than himself). You can find it [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/47955/20129).

Therefore even the explanation for the Vedic verses is the same simple one. **A younger brother Vishnu Trivikrama is respectfully praising the older and both are drinking Soma together with brotherly affection, even one pouring some of it for the other.**

---

### Conclusion

To answer your following question:

> Is it true that Vishnu is a minor God in the Vedas, who later became a major God? If no how do you explain the verses mentioned above and how do you establish the supremacy of Vishnu in the Vedas?

The Vedas mostly extol the residents of svarga and Vishnu as Trivikrama (being Indra’s younger brother) is included among them. However besides being included as Trivikrama, he is also supreme and eternal in the same Veda. **How can someone described as eternal, be only a minor deity?**

The verses as stated are grossly misrepresented in the question. After deriving a more accurate meaning, **they can be explained as the brotherly respect and affection shown by Vishnu playing the role of Trivikrama,** Indra’s younger brother.

---

**Extra Note:**  <sup>It is pertinent to note that the Vedic samhitas extol the residents of svarga, more than Brahman since through the Karmakanda (yajna) portion they get their nourishment. Hence in almost all places, the names belong mostly to the Adityas (Vishnu included), Vasus like Agni, Vishvedevas, Ribhus and such heavenly residents. Hence the Vishnu included in these lists is Trivikrama Vamana. If the supreme gods were to be shown as serving Indra, why are **Rudra and Hiranyagarbha not included** with these devatas? Because they did not incarnate among the Adityas. Vishnu incarnated and hence Vamana is included among the 12 Adityas. Where he’s spoken of as Brahman, he’s Brahman and not these devatas.</sup>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129037/discussion-on-answer-by-archit-proof-of-vedic-or-indic-origin-of-vaishnavism-mo).

Answer (score 1):

Harihi Om.

> **Side Note**: This answer shall be more from a historical point of view, than based on the Shaastras.

The main philosophy of Vaishnavism and the Supremacy of Shri Vishnu over all other devatas, comes from the Pancharaatra Aagamas. They themselves are mentioned in the Vedas:

> पुरुषो ह नारायणोऽकामयत अतितिष्ठेयं सर्वाणि भूतान्यहमेवेदं सर्वं स्यामिति स एतम् पुरुषमेधम् **पञ्चरात्रम्** यज्ञक्रतुमपश्यत्तमाहरत्तेनायजत तेनेष्ट्वात्यतिष्ठत्सर्वाणि भूतानीदं सर्वमभवदतितिष्ठति सर्वाणि भूतानीदं सर्वम् भवति य एवम् विद्वान्पुरुषमेधेन यजते यो वैतदेवम् वेद ।​

-Shatapatha Braahmana, Khanda 13, Adhyaaya 6, Braahmana 1, Mantra 1

> ऋग्वेदं भगवोऽध्येमि यजुर्वेदं सामवेदमाथर्वणं चतुर्थमितिहासपुराणं पञ्चमं वेदानां वेदं पित्र्यं राशिं दैवं निधिं वाकोवाक्य**मेकायनं** देवविद्यां ब्रह्मविद्यां भूतविद्यां क्षत्रविद्यां नक्षत्रविद्यां सर्पदेवजनविद्यामेतद्भगवोऽध्येमि ॥ ७.१.२ ॥

-Chhaandogya Upanishad, Prapaathaka 7, Khanda 1, Mantra 2

The Shatapatha Braahmana and Chhaandogya Upanishad are dated to **600-800 BCE and 1000 BCE (or earlier)** respectively. This straightaway debunks the claims against Shri Vishnu's Supremacy. The Shatapatha Braahmana mentions a Yajna of five nights performed by Shri Brahmaa (whose indweller is Shri Naaraayana), which was the origin of the Pancharaatra philosophy. The Chhaandogya Upanishad refers to the Pancharaatra philosophy by the name 'Ekaayana'. The Pancharaatra Aagamas, such as Purushottama Samhita (Adhyaaya 1, Mantra 10), Eeshvara Samhita (Adhyaaya 1, Mantra 19), Parama Purusha Samhita (Adhyaaya 1, Mantra 19) and Prashna Samhita (Adhyaaya 2, Mantras 38-39), themselves mention that 'Ekaayana' is a name of the Vaishnava philosophy.

Also, the Vedas have ample references of Shri Vishnu's Supremacy over other devatas such as Indra. For instance, the Taittireeya Aaranyaka, dated roughly to the same age of the Chhaandogya Upanishad, contains the Naaraayana Sukta.

> **नारायण परं ब्रह्म तत्त्वं नारायणः परः** ।
>
> नारायण परो ज्योतिरात्मा नारायणः परः ॥ ४ ॥
>
> **Naraayana is the Supreme Brahman, Naaraayana is the Supreme Reality.** Naaraayana is the Supreme Light, Naaraayana is the Supreme Aatma.

-Taittireeya Aaranyaka, Prapaathaka 10, Anuvaaka 13, Mantra 4

> तस्याः शिखाया मध्ये परमात्मा व्यवस्थितः ।
>
> स ब्रह्म स शिवः **सेन्द्रः** सोऽक्षरः परमः स्वराट् ॥ १२ ॥
>
> In the Middle of That Flame, the Supreme Aatma (Paramaatma) dwells. **He (Paramaatma) is Brahmaa, Shiva, Indra**, the Imperishable, the Autonomous Being.

-Taittireeya Aaranyaka, Prapaathaka 10, Anuvaaka 13, Mantra 4

Here, the devatas, including Indra, are said to be vibhutis of Paramaatma. Further, the Purusha Sukta mentions the birth of Indra from Purusha:

> च॒न्द्रमा॒ मन॑सो जा॒तः । चक्षोः॒ सूर्यो॑ अजायत ।
>
> **मुखा॒दिन्द्र॑श्चा॒ग्निश्च॑** । प्रा॒णाद्वा॒युर॑जायत ॥ १४ ॥
>
> “Chandra (the moon) was born from his mind, Surya (the Sun) was born from his two eyes. **Indra and Agni were born from his mouth**, and Vaayu was born from his breath.”

-Rgveda, Mandala 10, Sukta 90 (Purusha Sukta), Mantra 14

The Kena Upanishad (also dated to the 1st millennium BCE) mentions the inferior position of Indra in front of Brahman and therefore, his inability to be the Supreme Eeshvara. The Taittireeya Aaranyaka (Prapaathaka 8) and Katha Upanishad (Adhyaaya 2, Valli 3, Mantra 3) have a common mantra:

> भी॒षाऽस्मा॒द्वातः॑ पवते । भी॒षोदे॑ति॒ सूर्यः॑ ।
>
> भीषाऽस्मादग्नि॑श्चेन्द्र॒श्च । मृत्युर्धावति पञ्च॑म इ॒ति ।
>
> From fear of Him (Brahma), Agni burns, from fear of Him, Sūrya shines, **from the fear of Him, Indra (causes rain)**, Vāyu (blows), and Mṛtyu runs (to do his work) as the fifth [one].

This even has a direct Upa-Braahmana from the Bhaagavatam:

> (Shri Kapila said), "It is because of My supremacy that the wind blows, out of fear of Me; the sun shines out of fear of Me, and the lord of the clouds, Indra, sends forth showers out of fear of Me. Fire burns out of fear of Me, and death goes about taking its toll out of fear of Me."

-Bhaagavata Puraana, Khanda 3, Adhyaaya 25, Shloka 42

Now, the first Khanda of the Naaraayana Upanishad (dated by historians to somewhere in the 1st millenium BCE) itself says:

> नारायणादिन्द्रो जायते । नारायणात्प्रजापतयः प्रजायन्ते ।
>
> From Naaraayana, Indra is born. From Naaraayana Prajaapati is born.

The fourth Khanda of the Naaraayana Upanishad states:

> ब्रह्मण्यो देवकीपुत्रो ब्रह्मण्यो मधुसूदनोम् ।
> सर्वभूतस्थमेकं नारायणम् । कारणरूपमकार परं ब्रह्मोम् ।
>
> The son of Devaki is Brahmanya. Madhusudana is Brahmanya. Naaraayana who pervades all elements, who is one only, who is the cause Purusha and who is causeless, is known as Parabrahman.

The same passage is repeated in the Aatmabodha Upanishad too. Therefore, the Shaastras do state Shri Vishnu's Supremacy and it is very much baseless to say that abrahamic religions influenced Vaishnavism, when it existed centuries before the appearance of Christianity itself.